Nef and effective cones of a product-quotient surfaces
Let $G$ be a finite group acting on two smooth projective curves $C_1,C_2$ of genus $\geq 2.$ Consider the diagonal action of $G$ on $C_1\times C_2.$ We can assume that the action of $G$ is faithful on both the factors.
The minimal resolution of singularities $S$ of $X=(C_1\times C_2)/G$ is called a product-quotient surface of the quotient model $X.$ Here we assume $q(S)=0$ ($\iff C_i/G\cong \mathbb{P}^1,$ for $i=1,2$).
The surface $X=(C_1\times C_2)/G$ has only finitely many cyclic quotient singularities. This means, $\operatorname{Pic}(S)=\operatorname{Pic}(X)\oplus \mathbb{Z}[E_1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[E_2]\oplus\dots\oplus \mathbb{Z}[E_i];\ $ $E=\cup_i E_i,$ where $E_i^2=-b_i$, $E_i\cdot E_{i+1}=1,$ and $E_i\cdot E_j=0,$ otherwise. Here are my questions:
I) How well do we know the Picard group, cone of curves, nef and, (greedily) effective cones.
II) I am interested in finding an example where these can be explicitly described. I am having trouble coming up with an example of a curve of genus $\geq 2$ with $C/G\cong \mathbb{P}^1.$ From there I can try to resolve $X=(C\times C)/G$ to get the Picard group of $S$, but figuring out the nef and effective cones of $S$ seems bleak to me as I don't even know if $\operatorname{Nef}(C\times C)$ has a complete description for some $C$.
One example would be: Take an hyperelliptic curve $C$ and $X=(C\times C)/{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$. What would be $\operatorname{Eff}(X)$? (may be even in a particular example).
Any help is appreciated. Thank you. A good reference would be - Product-Quotient Surfaces: Results and Problems.

As you say, describing effective or ample cones on $C \times C$ is already very hard (if not impossible), so at best one could hope to describe explicit cases.
